# Add external dll to build directory using custom build path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition and it throws exceptions because it can't find some of its dlls that are holed up in my "Program Files" folder and the only solution I know is to manually copy said folder from "Program Files" to the directory of my project's `*.exe` (real professional, I know).

Since I'd like to have a little bit more professionalism than Microsoft I'd like to include the dlls in my project. However I'm fairly certain SQL Server CE won't work unless they are actually copied to the output directory, even if I could just include unmanaged dlls in my project.

However I don't want to have a random "amd64" (that's the name of the folder in "Program Files") folder in my project but if I don't - setting the dlls' `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy if newer` always copies them, replicating the folder tree. So if I put them in, say, a folder "External dependency" SQL Server CE will throw an exception, because it can't see "amd64" since in the output directory it will be "External dependency\amd64".

How do I tell Visual Studio to NOT replicate the directory tree exactly but copy files using custom rules?

Comment: Why not simply include the files as content, and stop depending on the Nuget package. Make sure to fix your app at x64 or x86!

Comment: @ErikEJ, I am not sure how to include the files as content and use the code in them.

Comment: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html?m=1

Comment: @ErikEJ, much obliged! I'll take a look at it.